# Is there in Interact/Ipywidgets something similar to Streamlit Multiselect?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets, streamlit, python-interactive

I need to query a Pandas `DataFrame` with a multiselection-like widget. It's pretty easy to do that with Streamlit ([streamlit multiselect example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOENA.gif)) but I wish to obtain the same through Ipython widgets.
Another point is that I have to deal with 184 possible selections.

Comment: Have you tried the SelectMultiple widget? https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html#SelectMultiple

Comment: @ac24 Yes but I'm looking for something easier than multi selection with `shift`+`command`/`ctrl` as in your link.